# MathJax + wkhtmltopdf and fonts

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, mathjax

I'm trying to convert a page using MathJax to a PDF using wkhtmltopdf. It's working fine except for the fonts used within the rendered math. I'm assuming they don't match because MathJax uses a font that wkhtmltopdf doesn't know about, but I'm not sure how to address this. Has anyone done this before?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use WOFF fonts, it should work with the latest version (0.12.0) in which was added for them.